# HTML Table and Checkboxes

Tags: php, html, checkbox, html-table

I have 1 table with checkboxes in it..
What I want to happen is to set the value of the checkbox to be the **student_id**

Here's my code:

```
      <?php 
        require_once('xcon.php'); 
        $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Students");
      ?>

      <table><br><br>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Choice</th>
                    <th>Student ID</th>
                    <th>Student First Name</th>
                    <th>Student Last Name</th>
                    <th>Level</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <?php
                 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){

                    echo "<tbody>";    
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td><input type = 'checkbox' name = 'checkbox[]' ></td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['student_id']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['fname']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['lname']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['yearlevel']."</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                    echo "</tbody>";
                }  
            ?> 

    </table>
```

I seem to be having the trouble of getting the logic in this and i got confused.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<td><input type = 'checkbox' name = 'checkbox[]' value='{$row['student_id']}'></td>";
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Add a `value` attribute to your checkbox with a value of the student id:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){

    echo "<tbody>";    
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><input type = 'checkbox' name = 'checkbox[]' value='".$row['student_id']."'></td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['student_id']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['fname']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['lname']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['yearlevel']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</tbody>";
}
```

**It's worth noting** that values of checkboxes will only be posted through to your form's target if the box is checked.

Comment: that would be my point.. i would want the values marked if the checkboxes are checked.. thanks for your help :)

Comment: No problem, glad I could assist.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking as follows.Add value atribute to checkbox input field and value should be $row['student_id'].

```
<?php
                 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){

                    echo "<tbody>";    
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td><input type = 'checkbox' name = 'checkbox[]' value='".$row['student_id']."' ></td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['student_id']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['fname']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['lname']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['yearlevel']."</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                    echo "</tbody>";
                }  
            ?>
```